# How to convert content of .gz files to lowercase

Tags: linux, zip

I have many .gz files and i need to convert the content of these files to all lowercase.  I tried:

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < input.gz > output.gz
```

but when I zcat "output.gz" I get this error:

```
zcat: output.gz: invalid compressed data--format violated
```

I also tried:

```
dd if=input.gz | gzip -c9 | dd of=output_1.gz conv=lcase
```

I get the same error.  What am I doing wrong, and what is the correct way of doing this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are feeding a compressed stream of data through tr, that won't work (well, it does something but definitely not what you want). You need to uncompress the file (eg using zcat), do the transformation magic and the recompress, like this:

```
zcat input.gz | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | gzip > output.gz
```